# Calling Fragment not showing when start new activity for result instead it show Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Parent Activity  have 3 fragment A,B and C.  When i select fragment B that showing one fab button  that call new Activity (Contact Activity) for result then i called finish() method in Contact Activity it did not back to fragment B instead it showing Parent Activity with A fragment.

onCreate() method set first fragment A.

```
if(messaging_fragment == null) {
        messaging_fragment = new all_messaging_fragment();
    }

fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, messaging_fragment).commit();
```

Parent Activity replace fragment using setFragment() method.

```
    private void setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String tag)
{
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
}
```

Fragment B called new Activity for result.

```
FloatingActionButton createMessageFloatButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.createNewGroupFloatbutton);
    createMessageFloatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent =  new Intent(getContext(),add_contact_list_activity.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent,2);
        }
    });
```

Contact Activity call the finish() method.

```
 ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_button_conatc_List_id);
    back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            setResult(2);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Comment: please, show us your code

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque this is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should 'add' messaging_fragment in the onCreate() to set first fragment A. Let us know if it is working.